# Array rotate and delete

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Based on the problem in GeeksForGeeks [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rotate-and-delete/0). I came across a solution [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/pkbUpmrCFi).

Can someone please help me understand the solution.
Primarily I need help in the following block:

```
if(n==1) cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
else if(n%2) {
    ll ind = n-3;
    ind = floor(ind/4);
    ind = 3+ind;
    cout<<arr[ind-1]<<endl;
} else {
    ll ind = n-2;
    ind = floor(ind/4);
    ind = 2+ind;
    cout<<arr[ind-1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I suggest you to take few examples and dry run the code. If after trying 4 to 5 good examples, you have any doubt, let us know the specific doubt.

Answer (score 5):

For each size of array, a particular position is the answer (i.e .independent of array elements).

For any array of size 8, 2 nd position (i.e. 3rd element) gives the answer.

Lets look at some examples:

- size=1, position=0

---

- size=2, position=1
- size=3, position=2
- size=4, position=1
- size=5, position=2

---

- size=6, position=2
- size=7, position=3
- size=8, position=2
- size=9, position=3

---

- size=10, position=3
- size=11, position=4
- size=12, position=3
- size=13, position=4

---

- size=14, position=4
- size=15, position=5
- size=16, position=4
- size=17, position=5

---

- size=18, position=5
- size=19, position=6
- size=20, position=5
- size=21, position=6

  ---

And so on.

For even size : `floor( (n-3)/4 )+2` gives the position.

For odd size  : `floor( (n-2)/4 )+1` gives the position.

Comment: It would have been better if you had given a mathematical proof

Comment: Don't you think its empirical, its just a pattern evolving in these type of problems

Answer (score 3):

For even size : `floor( (n-3)/4 )+2` gives the position.

For odd size : `floor( (n-2)/4 )+1` gives the position.

CORRECT:

For Odd size : `floor( (n-3)/4 )+2` gives the position.

For Even size : `floor( (n-2)/4 )+1` gives the position.